# Qt 4.7 Symbols not found error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7

Can anyone explain this error to me? It seems as though it is an error occurring with moc:

```
Undefined symbols:
make: Leaving directory `/Users/Dylan/Documents/programming/qt/Clock-build-desktop'
  "ClockDelegate::ClockDelegate(QObject*)", referenced from:
      AnalogClockDelegate::AnalogClockDelegate(QObject*)in AnalogClockDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Clock.app/Contents/MacOS/Clock] Error 1
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project Clock (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

ClockDelegate:

```
#ifndef CLOCKDELEGATE_H
#define CLOCKDELEGATE_H

#include <QObject>

class QTime;
class QWidget;

class ClockDelegate : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit ClockDelegate(QObject *parent);

    virtual void paintClock(QWidget *, QTime *) = 0;
};

#endif // CLOCKDELEGATE_H
```

AnalogClockDelegate:

```
#ifndef ANALOGCLOCKDELEGATE_H
#define ANALOGCLOCKDELEGATE_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QPoint>

#include "ClockDelegate.h"

class QWidget;

class AnalogClockDelegate : public ClockDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit AnalogClockDelegate(QObject *parent);

    void paintClock(QWidget *, QTime *);

private:

    void setupClockHands();

    void drawClockSurface(QWidget *clockView, QTime *);

    void drawHourComponent(QWidget *clockView);

    void drawMinuteComponent(QWidget *clockView, QTime *);

    void drawSecondComponent(QWidget *clockView, QTime *);

    QPoint   m_center;
    QPoint   m_hourHand[3];
    QPoint   m_minuteHand[3];
    QPoint   m_secondHand[2];

    QColor   m_hourColor;
    QColor   m_minuteColor;
    QColor   m_secondColor;
    QColor   m_clockFaceColor;
};

#endif // ANALOGCLOCKDELEGATE_H
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the "public" keyword, assuming ClockDelegate is a QObject. Otherwise you're not derived from a QObject so you cannot use Q_OBJECT.

```
class AnalogClockDelegate : public ClockDelegate
```

Comment: That was the problem. I was on the verge of ripping my hair out after an hour trying to eliminate this error. Thanks.

Comment: The other case is when the object you are deriving from is defined in a namespaces. You are likely to need to write the namespace(s) too. `public ns1::ns2::myClass` ...

Comment: I spoke too soon. Correcting for the above errors, I know get a "symbols not found" error. It seems moc doesn't like ClockDelegate or AnalogClockDelegate. I will edit the above.

Comment: Never mind, it turns out the constructor for the base class was missing a body. Thanks.